# Raspberry pi 4, UART4 and SPI0

Tags: spi, uart, config.txt, device-tree

Raspberry pi 4 has 4 usable `uart` ports, `uart 4` with `r`x in `gpio 9` and `tx` in `gpio 8`, share `rx` pin with `SPI0 miso0` pin.

I would like to use both peripherals no ate the same time, but in different moment of time.

In config.txt I enable uart4 with `dtoverlay=4`, but spi0 stop working. Is there any way to solve this issue. I am thinking in load `dtoverlay` dynamically, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I think you can use both UART and SPI (also I2C) "at the same time".

Answer (score 0):

See [Raspberry Pi4 UART](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697).

As you will see there is a conflict. While there are extra functions on the Pi4 there are only the same number of pins, so overlap is inevitable.

You need to consider your needs and pick appropriate options.

NOTE you can enable overlays on the fly e.g `sudo dtoverlay uart4`.

---

Changes to the OS mean that enabling some overlays on the fly is not currently working, although formerly it worked.

Comment: and for disable overlays on the fly? This is really helpful. My hardware is adapted to support the overlap pin. But sw does not allow me change between functionalities on the fly.

Comment: It does not work, the uart4 is not loaded, even the list of loaded dtoverlay is empty. I check with 'sudo dtoverlay -l'

Comment: @JeffersonAlexis "does not work" is futile because you haven't what "it" is. I use dtoverlay often in testing.